# OpenLayers.Control.Scale fails if parameters are specified

Tags: parameters, controls, scale, openlayers

In OpenLayers 2.13.1, map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.Scale({ geodesic: true })); fails (scale not visible in the map), if no parameters are specified scale control works OK.

Did anybody had this problem?

Regards, Alen

Answer (score 3):

The [`OpenLayers.Control.Scale`](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Control/Scale-js.html#OpenLayers.Control.Scale.OpenLayers.Control.Scale) constructor takes 2 parameters.

The first argument needs to be the DOM element.
The second argument is the options object.

```
OpenLayers.Control.Scale($('scaleDiv'), { geodesic: true })
```